# How can i solve this problem with history?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

TypeError: (0 , *history_history__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6*_.default) is not a function

My history.js file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory({
    forceRefresh: true
});
```

And the usage

```
<Button
  color="info"
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(userDeleted);
    history("/associated", {
      state: {
        devices: userDeleted.devices,
        email: userDeleted.email
      }
    });
  }}
  sx={{
    boxShadow: 2,
    bgcolor: '#2A293D',
    borderRadius: '2px'
  }}
>
  View devices
</Button>
```

I don't understand why it isn't working.

I tried some options but nothing was helpful, this is how my page look for now [image][image]

Comment: Maybe it's taking a browser's default history object. Can you try importing your function with some other name and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` is an object, not a function. You likely meant to call `history.push` or `history.replace`.

Example:

```
<Button
  color="info"
  onClick={() => {
    history.push(
      "/associated",
      {
        state: {
          devices: userDeleted.devices,
          email:userDeleted.email
        }
      }
    );
  }}
  sx={{
    boxShadow: 2,
    bgcolor: '#2A293D',
    borderRadius: '2px'
  }}
>
  View devices
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank u , that was the problem ! xD